# How to make a cribbage board with geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to model the holes in a cribbage board using geometry nodes.

[image]

The three main straight sections seem pretty easy, with a circle instanced on a line primitives. So far I have it set up like this:

1. Node group for a set of 5x2 holes
2. The group from (1) instanced on a line
3. Then at the turns... ???

[image]

I'm generally unsure what approach to aim for. Should I go for one big line, bent at the two turns, then instanced with circles? Or should it be several distinct pieces joined together (i.e. a straight section, then a turn, then another straight section, then another turn, then a final straight section.. all joined).

Is there a good way to do this with geometry nodes?

Comment: Asking "should I do it like this or that?" seems like you do not really have a problem and is most likely drawing opinion-based answers, which are considered off-topic here. Maybe you could rephrase your question to ask for a specific thing you try to accomplish but failed so far?

Comment: I think what's missing here is why you want to use geonodes - do you want adjustable size of the board? I imagine not adjustable number of holes (though maybe there are variances of the game). It might be a little bit too big of a project for Q&A here, and asking for guidance is not a great fit either… I think the most reasonable approach is to use "join geometry" to assemble the shape from multiple arcs and curve lines, actually you might want not to join at least not before you resample them and capture a boolean attribute where to spawn holes (using endpoint selection)…

Comment: Can we suggest methods other than GN? .. Unless you want a 'procedural' cribbage board..

Comment: Apologies, it's been a while since I've used the site and I think this type of "how can I create X?" question was fair game way back when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Turning them into holes is already a couple of little things.